# index.html won't open automatically

Tags: html, apache, server

We had an assignment to make a website for our Web Design class.
I was making it on my Raspberry Pi Apache webserver because of convenience.

I made all links that point to another page like this:

```
<a href="./folder/">Link to another page</a>
```

On Raspberry Pi it automatically loads index.html or index.php from that folder and it works perfectly fine.
But after downloading everything on the USB drive, I realized that those links won't load.

Microsoft Edge won't load those link at all, and Chrome/Firefox opens "Index of file:///" and lists all files in the directory.

I already made about a hundred of files with thousands of links like those.

The working website that I made can be accessed from anywhere, so I could technically just give the link to the professor, but he wants everything on a USB drive.

So, is there any way to make the browser on his PC load index.html files automatically or I have to change every link from ./folder/ to ./folder/index.html ?

And is there a way to do this automatically or I have to manually find and replace every link?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you're going to have to rename all of those links.

Fortunately most modern code editors support regular expression find & replace. I'll use Visual Studio Code as an example.
`Shift` + `Ctrl` + `F` pulls up the global (project-wide) search. There's a little button `.*` to toggle a regular expression search.

Assuming all of your links look like the example you showed you can put this in the search box:

```
href="\./(.+)/"
```

And this in the replace box:

```
href="./$1/index.html"
```

Here's what you started with:`<a href="./folder/">`

And Here's the end result: `<a href="./folder/index.html">`

I'd highly recommend reviewing the items found by this regex selector before you do a global replace. And as always make a backup of your project, or take some other precautions, because this selector might also find links in your project that you don't want changed.